# How can I get the time of game purchase on Google Play store

Tags: android, google-play

I have a paid game on Google Play store. Now I'm going to make it free with ads (use the same package). Everybody who have already paid for the game have to watch no ads. How can I determine theese users?

The first idea is to make a special version before make it free. The version will write a file on sd-card which will be the sign for the next free version to show no ads. But in this case, if a paid user installs the game to another device he will watch ads.

The snippet gives the time, but it is reseted if a user remove the game from a device and install it again:

```
PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
PackageInfo packageInfo = packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0);
long timestamp = packageInfo.firstInstallTime;
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Release a separate app that is free with ads and allow users to remove ads from that by making an in-app payment.  Keep your present paid app for those who may not have access to in-app payments or who just prefer no ads to begin with.  Call the latter your Pro (or whatever) version and the former your free version.

You can reduce the overhead of maintaining two apps by putting their common code in a library that both apps share.

I'm not sure how this will affect your rankings on the Play Store, as the ranking algorithms are intentionally inscrutable.  Paid purchases will likely be a small fraction of your free downloads, so maybe having your downloads divided will not hurt much, and the free/pro app model that I've described is so prevalent that Google may even have the ability to recognize it in its algorithms and assign proper credit where it is due.

Comment: Thank you for reply. But "make it free with ads (use the same package)" is the mandatory condition.